# Expectation of the inverse of sum of Bernoullis

Tags: probability-theory

Say we have

\begin{equation}
 B = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_{i}
\end{equation}

where $b_i$ is a bernoulli random variable with probability $p$ of being $1$ for all $i$. How to calculate

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\{  (1 + B)^{-1} \}
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been asked several times on the site. Using the identity $$E\left(\frac1{1+B}\right)=\int_0^1E(s^B)ds=\int_0^1E(s^b)^nds,$$ the value $E(s^b)=ps+1-p$, expanding $E(s^b)^n$ as a polynomial with respect to $s$ and integrating each monomial, one gets $$E\left(\frac1{1+B}\right)=\frac{1-(1-p)^{n+1}}{(n+1)p}.$$

Comment: Alternatively, conditioning on the last result $b_n$ yields two relations between the expectations of some $1/(1+B)$ and some $1/(2+B)$, yielding the recursion $$(n+1)E\left(\frac1{1+B_n}\right)=1+n(1-p)E\left(\frac1{1+B_{n-1}}\right),$$ which can then be solved, starting from $B_0=0$ almost surely.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: so long as $p\neq 1$, there exists a positive probability that $B=0$. What does that tell you about $\frac1B$?

Comment: Your're right thanks! I forgot to add the condition that at least one Bernoulli needs to be =1. I changed now B^-1 to 1+B^-1

Comment: @Peter I see you now changed $B^{-1}$ to $1+B^{-1}$, but the expected value of $1+B^{-1}$ is still infinite if $p<1$...

Comment: Once again, thanks... +1 should be inside the inverse !

Comment: @Peter I see. Well, the way the question is asked now, I really doubt there exists a closed form for calculating the expected value.